# How to display variables in Console from the Sources panel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm relatively new to debugging front-end code in Chrome so forgive me if this question is primitive.

Simply put, I'm in the Sources panel of Chrome's Dev Tools and am hovering over a variable called `_this.filters`.  I would like to display the contents of this variable in the Console.

How do I do that?

Robert

P.S. In case it matters, it's an AngularJS 1.7 app I'm working with.

Comment: set a break point and type it in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `console.log(_this.filters)` in the code where you would like to view the value.  It will print out to the console.

console.log takes comma separated of args too, so you can add multiple values.  I use this option to add tags at times to know what the value is e.g.

```
console.log('myfilters', _this.filters)
```